# Popping sound from sound system

Tags: electrical

I had built a new metal pole barn. I've had 200 amp service installed and an electrician connected the circuit box and earth ground. I'm doing the inside wiring myself. This is a party barn with a stage and large sound system. I also installed a wood burning stove with an electrical blower motor installed. The problem: When I am using the sound system and turn the blower on the stove off, I get a loud snap/pop noise thru the speaker system. I installed 20 amp breakers and 20 amp outlets and connected at the outlet the ground to ground, neutral to neutral and hot to hot. Also both are on separate circuits. What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Look into "RF interference".

Comment: The pop occurs when you turn the blower off, but not when you turn it on? Is there a spark in the switch when you turn it off? (sparks generate lots of interference).

Comment: It's fixed. I moved the circuit breaker for that line to the opposite buss. It working normal now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Motors do create a fair amount of electrical noise especially if the blower has a variable speed controller, an RFI filter may help as isherwood suggest or possibly an isolation transformer , in my riding arena we pipe music and I had to use step up transformers at the amp and step down at the speakers to get rid of. Ham radio and 60hz buzz on the feeds that were close to 180' but the poping is probably just motor noise. You could also move the feed for one of the outlets to the opposite leg so they are separated this may be the easy fix.

Comment: I can move to opposite leg pretty easily. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: You can also try using a power conditioning UPS on the stereo side of things.  This may also provide a brief period of time for the music to continue playing, in case of a power outage as well as preventing any brownouts from affecting performances.  IDK how reliable your power is, but it doesn't hurt to have a backup.  Also, this will help protect your system during electrical storms.  It's not a guarantee, but it's another level of protection.

Comment: It's working now, I moved it to the other buss. I have ordered "The Brick Wall" for my sound eqpt. I've used it for the house stuff and never lost an appliance. Thanks for your help.